# Implicit limits of compiler instruction reordering?

Tags: c#

When learning about locking mechanisms and concurrency recently, I came across compiler instruction reordering. Since then, I am a lot more suspicious about the correctness of the code I write even if there is no concurrent access to fields. I just encountered a piece of code like this:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var newValue = CalculateCachedValue(); 
cachedValue = newValue;
lastUpdate = now;
```

Is it possible that `lastUpdate = now` is executed before `cachedValue` is assigned the new value? This would mean that if the thread running this code was cancelled I would have logged an update that was not saved. From what I know now I have to assume this is the case and I need a memory barrier.

But is it even possible that the first statement is executed after the second? This would mean `now` is the time after the calculation and not before. I guess this is not the case because a method call is involved. However, there is no other clear dependency that prevents reordering. Is a method call/property access an implicit barrier? Are there other implicit constraints for instruction reordering that I should be aware of?

Comment: In the single-threaded case you cannot detect optimizations. Nothing to worry about. If you "abort" by using Thread.Abort all bets are off and a single abort call can permanently hose the AppDomain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NET jitter can reorder instructions, yes. Invariant code motion and common sub-expression elimination are important optimizations and can make code a great deal faster.

But that does not just happen willy-nilly.  The optimizer will only ever contemplate such an optimization if it *knows* that reordering will not have any undesirable side-effects.  In order for it to know, it first has to inline a method or property getter call.  And that will never happen for `DateTime.Now`, it requires an operating system call and those can never be inlined.  So you have a hard guarantee that no statement ever moves before or after `var now = DateTime.Now;`

And it actually has to make *sense* to move code and result in a measurable benefit.  There is no point in reordering the assignment statements, it does not make the code any faster.  Invariant code motion is an optimization that's applied to statements that are inside a loop, moving such a statement ahead of the loop so it does not get executed repeatedly pays off.  No risk of this at all in this snippet.  Sub-expression elimination is also nowhere in sight here.

Being afraid of optimizer-induced bugs is a bit like being afraid to step outside because you might be struck by a bolt of lightning.  That happens.  Odds are just very, very low.  A nice guarantee you get with the .NET jitter is that it gets tested millions of times every day.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I completely got the part with the system calls and the inlining. However, I'm not 100% satisfied with your last statement about optimizer-induced bugs. I think my question is not precise enough. I'll post another one that better illustrates the potential bug I'm worrying about.